# subsetting Panel Data conditional on consecutive strings of length

Tags: r, dplyr, subset, panel-data

I'm stuck trying to subset some panel data, i.e. ids within group, using `dplyr`.

I want to exact all `id`s, within each group, `grp` that has a `NUM` series with a minimum smaller than 2 and a maximum greater than 2. I've constructed a *minimal* working example below that should illustrate the issue.

I have been working with `filter()`, `row_number() == c(1,n())`, and tried to separate it out and merge, i.e. different types of `_join`, it back together, but I am stuck and I am now turning to the SO community for help.

#### What I got

A `tibble` like this,

```
df <- tibble(id = rep(0:1, c(8, 13)), grp = rep(c("01", "02"), c(13, 8)),
             NUM = c(-4, -3, -2, -1, 1, 2, 3, 4, -3, -2, -1,
                      1, 2, -3, -2, -1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)) %>% group_by(id, grp)
df %>% print(n=21)
#> # A tibble: 21 x 3
#> # Groups:   id, grp [3]
#>       id   grp   NUM
#>    <int> <chr> <dbl>
#>  1     0    01    -4
#>  2     0    01    -3
#>  3     0    01    -2
#>  4     0    01    -1
#>  5     0    01     1
#>  6     0    01     2
#>  7     0    01     3
#>  8     0    01     4
#>  9     1    01    -3
#> 10     1    01    -2
#> 11     1    01    -1
#> 12     1    01     1
#> 13     1    01     2
#> 14     1    02    -3
#> 15     1    02    -2
#> 16     1    02    -1
#> 17     1    02     1
#> 18     1    02     2
#> 19     1    02     3
#> 20     1    02     4
#> 21     1    02     5
```

#### What I am trying to get / desired outcome

```
df_out <- tibble(id = rep(0:1, c(9, 8)),
             grp = rep(c("01", "02"), c(9, 8)),
             NUM = c(-4, -3, -2, -1, 1, 2, 3,
           4, 5, -3, -2, -1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)) %>%  group_by(id, grp)
df_out
#> # A tibble: 17 x 3
#> # Groups:   id, grp [3]
#>       id   grp   NUM
#>    <int> <chr> <dbl>
#>  1     0    01    -4
#>  2     0    01    -3
#>  3     0    01    -2
#>  4     0    01    -1
#>  5     0    01     1
#>  6     0    01     2
#>  7     0    01     3
#>  8     0    01     4
#>  9     1    02    -3
#> 10     1    02    -2
#> 11     1    02    -1
#> 12     1    02     1
#> 13     1    02     2
#> 14     1    02     3
#> 15     1    02     4
#> 16     1    02     5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like so?

```
library(dplyr)
filter(df, any(NUM > 2) & any(NUM < -2))

# A tibble: 16 x 3
# Groups:   id, grp [2]
      id grp     NUM
   <int> <chr> <dbl>
 1     0 01    -4.00
 2     0 01    -3.00
 3     0 01    -2.00
 4     0 01    -1.00
 5     0 01     1.00
 6     0 01     2.00
 7     0 01     3.00
 8     0 01     4.00
 9     1 02    -3.00
10     1 02    -2.00
11     1 02    -1.00
12     1 02     1.00
13     1 02     2.00
14     1 02     3.00
15     1 02     4.00
16     1 02     5.00
```

In addition, if one whichs to subset on an exact values, say the first `NUM` is `-3` and last `NUM` is `5`, i.e. row 9-16 in the original data, tThis can be done like this,

```
df %>%
  group_by(id, grp) %>%
  mutate(first = first(NUM)
        ,last = last(NUM)) %>%
  filter(-3 == first & 5 == last) %>%
  select(-first, -last)  
#> # A tibble: 8 x 3
#> # Groups:   id, grp [1]
#>      id   grp   NUM
#>   <int> <chr> <dbl>
#> 1     1    02    -3
#> 2     1    02    -2
#> 3     1    02    -1
#> 4     1    02     1
#> 5     1    02     2
#> 6     1    02     3
#> 7     1    02     4
#> 8     1    02     5
```

The above is inspired by [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29377228/1305688).

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response! I realized I made the minimal working example too _minimal_. I do have cases where `NUM` strings are unequal, e.g. `-3, -2, -1, 1, 2` that should then not be counted. I'll update my mwe to something like this `df <- tibble(id = rep(0:1, c(8, 13)), grp = rep(c("01", "02"), c(13, 8)), NUM = c(-4, -3, -2, -1, 1, 2, 3, 4, -3, -2, -1, 1, 2, -3, -2, -1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)) %>% group_by(id, grp)` (but it might take a minute as I'll have to think it through)

Comment: might even be possible to shorten it to `filter(df, any(NUM > abs(2)))`

Comment: @EricFail, thanks for the edit, but I'd suggest you post it as another answer to the question. Also the 6th line should probably be `select(-first, -last)`.